# facebook subscribe button gives "unable to subscribe"

Tags: facebook

I added the facebook subscribe button to my site, but when I click it, the subscribe button gets replaced with an "Error" hyperlink, which (when clicked) gives "Unable to Subscribe: We were unable to create this subscription."  The hyperlink includes the query parameter "code=1529001" if that helps.

I tried googling this error but seems like I can't find it at all.

The page I am trying to subscribe to does allow subscribers (I turned it on in the settings).  Also, the "data-href" attribute of the subscribe button does, indeed, point to a valid facebook page URL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem too, but then I discovered that the subscribe button ("Follow") can only be used for personal Facebook accounts, not Facebook Pages (for businesses, organizations, websites, etc.). Perhaps this is the cause of your error as well?

<strike>If so, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a parallel replacement - only the much larger and more comprehensive "Like Box" is offered for Pages.</strike>

Edit: As pointed out by Evgeny, I somehow missed the Like button: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Thank you very much for this info, I hope this feature is open for buisnesses and organizations for following pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Like" social button (not the "Like Box"), it works just like the "Follow" just has a different text on it.